# Scaling graphics causes game to stop rendering

Tags: java, zooming, transform, render, 2d-games

I'm making a (currently rather simple) top-down 2D game in Java, and am having trouble implementing zooming.

It seems the only way I can scale is by reducing my width and height, and feeding a multiplied-up version to setPreferredSize(). I'd like to instead use an AffineTransform to scale my Graphics2D at render time, but including the `g2d.setTransform(transformer);` line gives everything being rendered as a null tile.

Without:
[image]
With:
[image]

I also tried feeding my class that handles tile/sprite rendering multiplied-up/divided down values for width and height, to the exact same result. Any ideas?

Here's my render method:

```
    bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3); // woo, triple buffering!
        return;
    }

    transformer.scale(scale, scale);

    // other stuff here . . . 

    // draw screen.pixels to pixels
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
    }

    // draw
    g2d = (Graphics2D)bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g2d.setTransform(transformer);
    {
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        /* g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
         * g.setFont(new Font("Veranda", 0, 50));
         * g.drawString("B: " + Mouse.b(), 80, 80);
        */
    }
    g2d.dispose();

    bs.show(); // blit/show buffer

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
```

I'm using Eclipse IDE and no premade game engines on Java1.6. I'm rendering onto a Canvas in a JFrame.

Comment: As I recall, a scaling transformation will also scale the location points

Comment: Is there a standardised method for scaling without doing so? Or will I need to go through and counter each by hand?

Comment: Off the top of my head, no.  You could try using `AffineTransformation#setToTranslation` to translate the graphics original

Comment: setToTranslation stops it displaying void tiles, but it functions to translate values along (offsets everything). Looking through the AffineTransformation api page for a more appropriate function.

Comment: using setToScale seems to prove that you were right about scaling location points- as I adjust the scaling factor in-game i can see everything move off to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I would take at Slick2d http://www.slick2d.org/

It has its own Image class, and the way it handles re-sizing images is very easy to work with.

Comment: I'm not too keen on moving to a pre-existing engine at this point. Sure, my game's far from complete, but my engine's a bit too mixed into the rest to easily change.

Comment: On reflection, I think I'm going to have to do a lot of rewriting anyway, so I might use slick. Unfortunately, the site is down. Anywhere else I can get good resources on it?

Comment: [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?f455iu0bh14imbi) is an example that is setup and ready for use. This already includes the libraries you need. You are going to have to change the native library location though, to satisfy your path in order for it to work. Right click on your project folder, "Build path --> configure build path" then go to the library tab, and drop down the arrow on lwjgl.jar, and set the Native library location to the folder of your operating system.

Comment: Also, having a very messy engine will frustrate you in the long run. Slick takes care of the details so you can actually get to making the game. Also, all of this is assuming you are using eclipse.